# PHP Code works in Chrome, but not IE

Tags: php, html, forms

This code here works in Chrome, where the database list shows in the drop down box, but when in IE it is just listed out not in the drop down box:

```
if (!$result)
{
/*echo $query;*/
$message = 'ERROR: ' . sqlsrv_errors();
return $message;
}
else
{ 
$i = 0;
echo '<html><body><table><tr><td>&nbsp;Forte ID:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr><select id="ForteID" name="ForteID"><table width="150"><tr>';
while ($i < sqlsrv_num_rows($result))
{
    $meta = sqlsrv_fetch($result, $i);
    echo '<td>' . $meta->name . '</td>';
    $i = $i + 1;
}
echo '';

while ( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ))
{
    $count = count($row);
    $y = 0;
    echo '<tr><option>';
    while ($y < $count)
    {
        $c_row = current($row);
        echo '<td>' . $c_row . '</td>';
        next($row);
        $y = $y + 1;
    }
    echo '</option></tr>';
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt ($result);

echo '</table></select></body></html>';
}
sqlsrv_close( $connection);
?>
```

Let me know if I need to describe anything better.  Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

This is what I have now:

```
<?php
$serverName = 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS';
$connectionInfo = array('Database'=>'database', 'UID'=>'username', 'PWD'=>'password','ReturnDatesAsStrings'=>true,);
$connection = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

$query = '  SELECT Column1
        FROM database.dbo.Reps 
        ORDER By Column1';
$result = sqlsrv_query($connection,$query);

// Move the data to a simple array to simplify presentation code.
$resultAsArray = array(); 
while ( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC )) {
$resultAsArray []= $row;
}
?>

<form method="get" action="getlog.php">
<select>
<?php foreach ($resultAsArray as $row): ?>
<option value="<?php= $row['Column1'] ?>"><?php= $row['Column1'] ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="getLog" value="Get Log">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot nest a `<table>` within a `<select>`. If it works anywhere it's a miracle.

Comment: Yes. What @DaveRandom said. Open in Browser, view source, copy and paste the HTML in your question. PHP is independent of your browser.

Comment: It works in chrome right now.  How would you suggest this goes then, because every place I place the     <select>     It just lists out the results not in the drop down.

Comment: @DaveRandom, he has wrong html syntax ...

Comment: when I copy and paste the source HTML into a test file and pull it up in Chrome it still works perfectly fine.

Comment: This is a nice example of how chrome does manage to compensate for silly markup. But if anything, this is exactly why I feel that it wouldn't hurt if browsers were a bit less forgiving...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yea, I would of liked to know before I actually started having other people start testing it as well.

Comment: @ncurran217: You can always use the [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/), of course

Answer (score 4):

As the first comment stated, nesting tables in a select should not be expected to work.  I'm assuming you're just trying to get the contents of a db query into a select.  To that end, you just need `<select>` and `<option>` tags.  Further, to help make your code a lot more readable (and maintainable!) break up your code into two parts, the DB access and the presentation.  I don't use the sqlsrv libraries, so I'm going to just use pseudo-ish code for the db access.

```
<?php
$resultSet = db_call_to_load_the_data();

// Move the data to a simple array to simplify presentation code.
$resultAsArray = array(); 
while ($row = $resultSet->getNextRow()) {
    $resultAsArray []= $row;
}
```

Then to display it...

```
<select>
<?php foreach ($resultAsArray as $row): ?>
    <option value="<?= $row['value_column'] ?>"><?= $row['display_value_column'] ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

I presume that's what you're looking for.  My apologies if I oversimplified things.

Comment: Now to match SQL Server to yours.

Comment: If the variable already has data in it then that will clear it out.  Otherwise if the variable is new then PHP should just create it as necessary.  (It's possible that some pedantic php.ini settings will result in that producing a warning.)

More than anything, however, it helps the reader of the code to know what is going on there.  "We're starting with an empty array."  That way they don't have to go searching to see if the variable already has anything in it.

Comment: I saw that after words and actually thought about it.  As of right now I have nothing in the select box.  EDIT: I think where the code differs is this `while ($row = $resultSet->getNextRow())` As it gave me an error with the `getNextRow`, since I am using SQL Server.

Comment: the `->getNextRow()` was pseudocode.  Your db access may have a slightly different paradigm for iterating through the result set.  Based on your original code I'm guessing `sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC )` or some variation is what you're looking for.

Comment: that is what i put while ( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ))

Comment: @ncurran217 - update your question with your code, not Wil's answer.  Delnan, thumbs up for the rollback.

Comment: From what I can tell is that it looks like the options should be there but they are all blank, because if I take out the `<?= $row['display_value_column'] ?>` and put in just Select, every option shows Select.